# Validation message doesn't show up when submitting using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm developing a Contact page form, so when I submit the validation text doesn't show for the 3 fields although I followed the right steps , see the image below

[image]

Here's my ContactViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ContactViewModel
    {
        [Required] 
        public string Name { set; get; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { set; get; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(4096, MinimumLength =10)]
        public string Message { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Here's the Contact View

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ContactViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = " Contact Page ";
}


@section scripts {
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}

<h2>Contact me</h2>
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
<label asp-for="Name"></label>
<input asp-for="Name"/>
<span asp-validation-for="Name" ></span>

<label asp-for="Email" ></label>
<input asp-for="Email" type="email"/>
<span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>

<label asp-for="Message" ></label>
<textarea cols="40" rows="4" asp-for="Message" ></textarea>
<span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>

<div>
    <input type ="submit" value="Send Message"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js file has been loaded correctly?

Comment: You have 3 times `<span asp-validation-for="Name" ></span>` (the 2nd and 3rd ones need to be for `Email` and `Message`)

Comment: You have added form controls, but you don't have any <form>, and that's is one of the reasons why messages won't be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead using ASP.NET MVC helper classes

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ContactViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "MyForm" })) 
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m. Email)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m. Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m. Email)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Message)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

You can also add custom validation messages by updating the `[required]` attribute in your model to the example below:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Name.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to add the jquery script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

so you can do client side validations.
And use your validations on **span** element and not on **input** , like this

```
<span class=text-danger" asp-validation-for="Name" required="required" minlength="5"></span>
```